# Is it haram to use a wallet which has a design like a horse and a deer?

Tags: halal-haram

I have bought a wallet but discovered that it has a design like a horse and a deer in it. Is it haram to use?

Comment: Islam is more merciful and there is no harm in having such wallet.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no apparent evidence regarding the Hormah (being haram) for using by horse design as you inquired

> Is it haram to use a wallet which has a design like a horse and a
>   deer?

But I found a relevant issue which has illustrated regarding Salah or Namaz. It has inquired concerning saying prayer with the shirt on which has the shapes of animals, the presented response is that

> It is considered as a Makruh practice to say prayers with a shirt
>   which includes the images…

As a consequence, perhaps it would be better endeavor not to say prayer when you’re carry that (although, on the whole, it doesn’t seem to be impermissible).

And Allah Knows Best

---

**References:**

[www.islamquest.net in Farsi (Persian)](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa24113) / [In French](http://www.islamquest.net/fr/archive/question/fa24113)

Answer (score -3):

Assalaamu alaikum warehmatullahi wabarakatuhu,

References from hadith (halaal):
Narrated Maimunah (RAA): The Prophet (Sallallahu alayhi wa sallam) passed by a dead sheep being dragged along by (some people). Thereupon he said to them, "Why didn't you make use of its skin?" They told him, "It is a dead animal (i.e. had died a natural death, without being slaughtered)." He said to them (Sallallahu alayhi wa sallam). "Water and the leaves of mimosa flava purify it"
[Related by Abu Dawud and anNasa'i]

Hadeeth of Zayd ibn Thaabit (may Allah be pleased with him), from the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) who said: “Tanning the skin of the dead animal (that died without being slaughtered) is its purification.”

Hadith relating to skins (haram):
Narrated by Abu Dawood, 4239; classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh Abi Dawood, 3566. 
It was narrated from Mu’aawiyah that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The angels do not accompany a group of people among whom there is a tiger skin."

POINTS
 THE HALA ANIMALS SLAUGHTERED PROPERLY/IMPROPERLY 
The use of hide from these animals is permissible E.g. the cow, goat, sheep, and camel they are halal to eat.
ANIMALS WHOSE MEAT AS WELL AS SKIN IS HARAM
The allowance/permissibility is that the meat is haraam and the hide is also impure and haram. eg:- Tiger, Shark, lion, pig, snake.

**Conclusion**:- Your wallet has only a design like a horse/deer patterns which is not haram. Even if they were made out of their (animal) hides (skins) it would still be permissible for you to use. As long as it does not have any pictures or faces. (It won't be haram but, the Prophet Muhammed SAW ordered Ali RA to blot out and taking down photos/faces/pictures/figures).

Comment: Could you clarify what the difference between a horse/deer "design" (which you imply is halal) and a horse/deer "picture" (which you imply is makruh)?

Comment: Design means its fur prints ressembling it's body pattern. Eg:- In giraffe it has brown spots on its body, if that pattern is used it is halal but not the picture of giraffe (face).

Comment: The answer seems to be irrelevant, as it refers to the use of animal skin, rather than animal figure on the wallet

Comment: Not quite, I mentioned reference so as to make it clear that even if he used the real skin of halal (not haram animals) animals it's permissible to use the product. But it should not have any faces or figures of the animal. If you want to know the answer to this too I have reference.

Answer (score -3):

It doesn't matter, don't take everything literally. We pray to Allah with our intentions of praying to Him, **minor things** like this wouldn't matter to Allah .